# Is there a phrase for the re-establishment of friendship with someone?

Tags: phrase-requests

What is the phrase which means to re-establish a cordial relation between two friends which used to be bitter?

Comment: *reconciliation*

Comment: How close were they before, how bitter was the dispute, and how close is the new re-established friendship? This is important because there are several good answers given, and the answer to this question would help inform the choice of which one to go with.

Answer (score 48):

The term you are looking for is ​to ***[reconcile](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reconcile):***

> - ***When two people are reconciled, they become friendly again after they have argued:***
>
>   - *They were finally reconciled with each other, after not speaking for nearly five years.*

Cambridge dictionary

Comment: I have never heard this used outside of a romantic relationship in the US.  Maybe this is an England thing, but in all not a great word choice.

Comment: Oh..Mr.@RyeBread..where have you been so far? You've been absent for ages. Hope you are back to give your invaluable contribution to the site. As for the usage of "reconcile," the term is definitely  used also outside romantic contexts: BrE : http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reconcile - AmE : https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=reconcile&submit.x=46&submit.y=39

Comment: I certainly don't trust cambridge on all word usage cases.  The general definition is fine, but it isn't used that way - at all.  If you said that you reconciled with your friend Mark - people would think you and Mark were gay (not that there is anything wrong with that!)

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd - also the AHD offers exemples you should look at. The way you personally use the term is interesting but not really relevant. Please provide reliable references to support your view.

Comment: Well that is why I don't frequent the site.  You and others use "sources" like they are the law.  It is sad.  This isn't math.  There are not many questions on here that equate to a theorem with a defined answer and method.  If cambridge had all the answers people would just look there.  But it is often mistaken, because it guesses on usage based on (too) basic statistical analysis.  Just gung-ho saying the cambridge is right without experience to back it up is just as bad or worse than just having an opinion on usage.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd - that is an interesting point you could bring up on a Meta. This is not the place to discuss it.

Comment: I don't care enough to move it to meta.  It is apparent that many of the voters on the site don't understand English usage, which I have already brought up in meta - and others agreed.  My point was for your answer.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd - Are you claiming that your experience leads you to a more accurate answer than Cambridge, AH, the answerer here and the people who voted on this answer? If that is what you are up against, you may want to reevaluate your certainty on the issue to something less than 100%. By the way, as a native english speaker, using reconcile in this sense seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd You still need SOME sort of source for your knowledge. Maybe they people you've spent your life around just haven't used it outside of a romantic context. Maybe they have and you just haven't noticed/didn't realise because of your (mistaken IMHO) impression of the limit to the word's meaning. I've certainly had occasions where I thought very clearly I knew exactly what a word/expression meant and actually it turned out I was using it wrong all the time, and I'm sure most people have. No one person can be the ultimate source of English usage information! Clearly 22 people disagree.

Comment: @Muzer - those 22 people voting were vetted out as being intelligent native English speakers right?

Comment: I am a native AmE speaker and I have heard and used the term `reconcile` many times. I have never been aware of any restriction to romantic relationships when using that word. I *have*, on the other hand, heard and used it for anything from general friendship to business acquaintances as well as in reference to romantic relationships. I believe this word is perfect for the OP's request. It is a fairly common word, and from my experience, perfectly suited for a variety of interpersonal relations. @RyeɃreḁd - out of curiosity, what region of the U.S. are you from?

Comment: "reconcile" is used all the time, in the USA, in say a business context - it's totally normal.  (You can google zillions of examples.)

Comment: I am a native English speaker from the US, and I rarely hear reconcile used in a romantic context. It's much more often used in the context of a family relationship (which does include marriage). "Bob and his father were estranged for years, but they finally reconciled." "Steven and Berrie were separated and considering divorce, but they reconciled for the sake of the children."

Answer (score 27):

My father, a WWII veteran, would have called it "burying the hatchet."

To [bury the hatchet](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bury+the+hatchet) means:

> to forget about arguments and disagreements with someone and to become friends with them again.

[Cambridge Idioms Dictionary, 2nd ed.]

Comment: Hello, AI Maki. Your answer was (unfortunately) flagged automatically as low-quality for its length. Please try to cite some references as I've done in the edit. Your post seems to answer the question. Please review my edit and try to follow the format next time you answer a question. Good luck.

Comment: @Rathony Nice courtesy!

Comment: As an interesting (to me at least) aside this phrase reported has its origins in Iroquois Confederacy.  In pre-colonial Northern America Native Americans buried their weapons as a ceremonial symbol of peace.  More reading [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burying_the_hatchet)

Comment: @RichardKayser Wow. I blush...

Comment: Dolores O'Riordan likes this answer.

Comment: @Rathony That wasn't the intended effect. :-)

Answer (score 20):

The **phrase** you are looking for is [**"make up"**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make%20up)

> - to become reconciled (quarreled but later made up) to reconcile with someone; to end a disagreement (with someone).
> - to forgive someone and be friendly with them again after an argument or disagreement [(from **CD**)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/ingles/make-up)

*Bill and Max decided to make up. They made up with each other and are now very good friends.*

Comment: "kiss and make up" is a common phrase _(often used when you don't literally mean for them to kiss, you're just picking on them)_

Comment: Not to be confused with "kiss and make out". I made that mistake **once**...

Comment: "Kiss and make up" is often used in a sort of joking/lighthearted context, since it's the sort of thing you'd say to children. You wouldn't say it for something really serious (I know @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft alluded to this but I just wanted to make it clear!)

Answer (score 17):

A colorful way to put it is to "[rekindle](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rekindle) the relationship".

Oxford definition for "rekindle":

> Revive (something lost or lapsed):
>   ‘he tried to rekindle their friendship’

Comment: That would imply a romantic relationship to me (British English)

Comment: I think this is most often used in reference to romantic relationships, probably due to its allusion to fire and the passion it represents. That suits poets and novelists just fine. But to my Californian ear it makes sense to me platonically.

Answer (score 12):

How about ***reunite*** or ***get back together***?

M-W:

> [***reunite***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reunite): to
>   come together again

***Get back together*** means exactly what the words say.

Or how about ***bury the hatchet*** or ***let bygones be bygones***?

> [***bury the
>   hatchet***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bury+the+hatchet): to
>   forget about arguments and disagreements with someone and to become
>   friends with them again
>
> [***let bygones be
>   bygones***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/let+bygones+be+bygones):
>   forgive someone for something he or she did in the past

Another possibility is ***rapproachement***.

M-W:

> [***rapproachement***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rapprochement):
>   establishment of or state of having cordial relations

Comment: +1 for bury the hatchet.  That said, IMHO "reunite" is not really appropriate as it does not imply a reconciliation has occurred.

Comment: @Lumberjack Thanks for the comment. To me, it means that enough of a reconciliation has occurred for the parties to reunite after who knows how significant their differences. But point taken.

Comment: I like "rapproachement", Richard, even though it has echoes of international rather that interpersonal relations.

Comment: @BoldBen Funny thing in the origin language, French, it seems to mean just that.

Answer (score 10):

"mend fences"

See http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mend%20fences

to improve or repair a relationship that has been damaged by an argument or disagreement.

- She mended fences with her father.
- She and her father are trying to mend their fences.
- After the election, he spent a lot of time mending political fences.

Other related idioms to say are "build bridges", "it is water under the bridge" or "we moved past it", "let's move past it", "let's put it behind us".

Comment: I was always puzzled by "mending fences".  To me that is more or less literally synonymous with "building walls" which is generally indicative of a failing relationship.  Having a barrier between two people.  I'm not criticising, just an observation on the weirdness of English.

Comment: Consider the famous poem, "Mending Wall" by Robert Frost, in which two neighbors in the spring, by common agreement, repair the walls between their fields so there is no dispute over the boundaries. https://www.poets.org/poetsorg/poem/mending-wall  Also note that when a person "crosses the line" they commit a trespass. The boundaries of propriety need to be reset after such an incident.

Comment: In a more agrarian society, fences are more for animals than people, and they don't just keep others out, they keep yours in. If you had broken fences, and your cows got into the neighbor's field and ate their crops, then mending said fences would certainly improve your relationship with your neighbor.

Answer (score 3):

***[Pick up where you left off](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pick+up+where+we+left+off)***

> pick (something) up where (one) left off: To resume or start (something) again from the last point where one had previously stopped. *If it's OK with you, I'd like to go out on a date and try to pick up where we left off! OK, now that the rain's stopped, let's pick this game up where we left off!*

Example:

> After a three-year break in our friendship, Tomás and I picked up where we left off.

Answer (score 1):

To **reconnect** with old friends

This phrase is more about friends that had a good relationship but lost contact for a while. It's only semi-related to your question since you specifically mentioned a bitter relationship, but it answers the question in the title.